# Predicted vs observed plot with diagonal line and deviation

Tags: excel, charts, scatter-plot, prediction

I am trying to plot predictions vs observations in a scatter plot showing the predicted values in x and the observed in y, so a perfect fit should be shown in the diagonal. Is there any way to plot that diagonal in excel as a line, so it is easier to see if the result is close to the ideal? Also, my model has a standard error that I would also like to show as upper and lower line. Something like this:
[image]

Any ideas how I could add the lines in excel? Thanks !!

[edit]
This happens if I add a new series to draw the diagonal line as a line plot:
[image]
Where 'line 1' gives me what is shown in the center image after I add a new series, and 'line 2' the one of the right if I add the cells to a existing axis. What I'm doing wrong? thanks

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use linear regression provided in the analysis tool pack?

Comment: Yes. I made the models in spss using curve estimation, so they are not linear models. And I also need to add the secondary lines... I think I'll need to draw them manually in a different software. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Create a new series for each line, with just two points for each series.

For the diagonal, the first point is at the intersection of the axes and the second is at the top right of the charted area. Format the series with a suitable line and no data points.

For the upper and lower lines, same technique but the first point is where the line intersects the y or x axis respectively.

Comment: Thank you, I though about adding a new series and joining the points with a line plot, but haven't been able. Could you give me more details? For the diagonal, if it e.g. starts from 0,0 and ends in 5,5, when I make a new series with only 0 and 5, the 0 point shows well, but the 5 one does not appear (I guess it is in the z axis?). And if I add it to the other series (x for example), the line gets affected by the numbers in y. I'm gonna add an image to the question to explain this better. Thanks !